# How to $pull documents in nested array of documents in MONGODB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> How to remove data from documents which have userId = "fadd66e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4" in parentHierarchy and have  organizationId = "d44a90c0-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de".

This is Documents.

```
    [ {
        "name": "ABC", 
        "organization": [
           {
             "organizationId": "d44a90c0-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de",
             "parentHierarchy": [
                {
                    "privelege": "Admin",
                    "userId": "fadd66e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                },
                {
                    "privelege": "Manager",
                    "userId": "fadd56e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                }
              ]
            },
          {
            "organizationId": "d44a90c1-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de",
            "parentHierarchy": [
                {
                    "privelege": "Admin",
                    "userId": "fada66e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                },
                {
                    "privelege": "Manager",
                    "userId": "fndd56e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                }
            ]
         }
       ]
    },
    {
        "name": "PQR", 
        "organization": [
           {
             "organizationId": "d44a90c0-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de",
             "parentHierarchy": [
                {
                    "privelege": "Admin",
                    "userId": "fadd66e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                },
                {
                    "privelege": "Manager",
                    "userId": "fadd56e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                }
              ]
            }
       ]
    }]
```

> Output Document should be come in this format(which have no parenthierarchy in this organisationId "d44a90c0-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de").

```
   [ {
        "name": "ABC", 
        "organization": [
           {
             "organizationId": "d44a90c0-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de",
             "parentHierarchy": [
                {
                    "privelege": "Manager",
                    "userId": "fadd56e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                }
              ]
            },
          {
            "organizationId": "d44a90c1-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de",
            "parentHierarchy": [
                {
                    "privelege": "Admin",
                    "userId": "fada66e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                },
                {
                    "privelege": "Manager",
                    "userId": "fndd56e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                }
            ]
         }
       ]
    },
    {
        "name": "PQR", 
        "organization": [
           {
             "organizationId": "d44a90c0-3f04-4dbd-97f0-cd1be3baf2de",
             "parentHierarchy": [
                {
                    "privelege": "Manager",
                    "userId": "fadd56e5-97b9-4ae0-86ca-7922bf9d1da4"
                }
              ]
            }
       ]
    }]
```

> **I have used query like this but not return  proper data.**

```
  var condition = {"organization.organizationId":condition.orgId,
            "organization.parentHierarchy.userId": userdata[0]._id}
  var update = {
       "$pull":{"organization":
                  {"organizationId": condition.orgId,
                   "parentHierarchy":{"userId": userdata[0]._id}}}
 }

 db.collection('users').update(condition, update, {multi: true}, 
    function(error, documents) {
    if(error){
        console.log("error in to update parentHierarchy");

    }
    else{
        console.log("updated Documents");

    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Pull operator works by applying query as it was top level document so when the criteria finds the document it removes documents in `organization`embedded array.

You've to use positional operator to remove documents in `parentHierarchy` embedded array.

Query criteria locates the `organization` element followed by `$pull` to remove all the documents matching userid in `parentHierarchy` array of documents.

```
var condition={"organization.organizationId":condition.orgId}
var update={"organization.$.parentHierarchy":{"userId": userdata[0]._id}}
```

Comment: I tried which you had told condition and update.But corresponding all data gets empty(means completely data has removed).

Comment: Are you trying on the same data set ? Can you add  an edit   showing your query ? I've verified the query for the data provided.